# Joomla 3: import rss feed

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, rss

I could not find any plugin, which could help me with importing rss feed (like this: http://www.verzekeringsnieuws.nl/rss/algemeen.xml)

I found  feedGator, but it didn't work in joomla 3...

maybe there are some ways to import rss as articles?

Answer (score 3):

Although using an existing extension might be easier, if you have some knowledge of PHP you could also create your own feed reader (using [simplexml_load_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) ), in order to have full control on how the data is used and displayed. For the most basic usage, a [module](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module) with the following code would output your feed items:

```
<?php 
    $feed = "http://www.verzekeringsnieuws.nl/rss/algemeen.xml";
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($feed);

    echo '<h1>'. $rss->channel->title . '</h1>';

    foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
       echo '<h2><a href="'. $item->link .'">' . $item->title . "</a></h2>";
       echo "<p>" . $item->pubDate . "</p>";
       echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";
       echo '<p><a href="'. $item->link . '" class="btn btn-primary">Read more...</a></p>';
    } 

?>
```

Once you have the data you can present it as you want, manipulate it, save it to your database and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your are in the right direction, but you only have to choose other extension. FeedGator has not been updated in a while.

- [AutoTweetNG](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/social-web/social-share/autotweet-ng)
- [obFullTextRSS](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/social-web/social-edition/obfulltextrss)
- [obGrabber](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/obgrabber)

You can find more in JED, [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions?searchall=rss%20grabber&filter[tags][0]=233&filter[core_catid]=&filter[includes]=&filter[versions]=&filter[type]=&filter[hasdemo]=&filter[newupdated]=&filter[score]=&filter[favourites]=&dir=DESC&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1&start=36)

Answer (score 1):

you may try rss2article:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/rss-2-article

it is really powerfull

Comment: This hyperlink is now broken -- to the disappointment of a new user (who does not have the privilege to leave a comment under your answer).  Please update this post so that researchers can find what you are recommending.